Consulta sobre una web "antigua" guardada en una carpeta dentro de "public_html"
Hay una web que estoy rediseñando en Figma y luego desarrollar con Wordpress. La web anterior estaba desarrollada con HTML por lo que entiendo. Cuando le instalaron Wordpress a su servidor en public_html crearon una carpeta de nombre "OLD-WEB" que contiene la web anterior en el cual necesito visualizarla para extraer el contenido para rediseñarla.
El problema que cuando quiero ingresar con la url correcta a la web anterior no se visualiza. La web es https://wcaudiovisual.com.au/
Pero cuando quiero ingresar a https://wcaudiovisual.com.au/OLD-WEB no carga. Dejo capturas de pantalla de los archivos "FTP" + lo que hay en la carpeta OLD-WEB. Tambien hay un archivo "sitemap.xml" que contiene las url de la web anterior y son archivos html pero no los encuentro en esta carpeta OLD-WEB. Sera que la persona que instalo WP, borro las paginas html de la web anterior?


Esos html seguramente son generados por wordpress cuando son invocados, no los encontrarás así. Consejo: Instálate un LAMP local en tu ordenador y te pones el OLD-WEB en la carpeta pública y configuras el apache como si fuera el sitio antiguo, y luego usa el archivo hosts para mentir a tu ordenador y que cuando intentes navegar por esa web se vaya a tu locahost en lugar del que hay en internet

Mira todos estos errores.
http://wcaudiovisual.com.au/OLD-WEB/error_log

[08-Jul-2019 10:08:13 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  The file /home/wcaudiov/application/application.php was encoded by the ionCube Encoder for PHP 5.0 and cannot run under PHP 7.1 or later.

Tu PHP es más nuevo, tendrías que programarlo todo desde cero y adaptarlo a una versión nueva.

Genial entiendo. Entonces la web anterior ya no se va a visualizar por la nueva version de PHP que seguramente se acttualizo cuando se instalo Wordpress

@GustavoVarela Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

@GustavoVarela Como se puede ver en el log, también hay problemas de permisos en las carpetas. <b>/home/wcaudiov/application/application.php</b> is not permissioned for 27.50.93.76 in Unknown on line 0 y wcaudiov no está en la ruta púbica.

Por lo que me comentaron la web anterior no estaba hecha con Wordpress. El problema se genero cuando instalaron Wordpress para dejar la pagina en contruccion, pero quisieron guardar la pagina antigua en la carpeta "OLD-WEB"
Yo quiero saber si hay o existe una posibildad de ver la web anterior?

Ademas el error_log es del 2019, esta web se empezo a trabajar en el año 2023.

Ya pude visualizar la web. El tema que instalaron wordpress y la web antigua la movieron a una carpeta "OLD-WEB" dentro de public_html, cuestion que meti toda la instalacion de WP en una carpeta y movi los archivos de la web anterior al principio en public_html

@GustavoVarela Te quedó buenísima la web.

@GustavoVarela La volví a ver y ahora tira error 500. ¿Qué pasó?

El problema era que se estaba utilizando PHP 7.2, actualice desde cPanel a PHP 5.6 y se soluciono. Igual es una web que tiene mas de 10 años al parecer, yo no la hice, estoy haciendo un rediseño de esta pagina un cliente y la quiere en Wordpress. Todavia se estan diseñando las pagina en Figma, Pero ya el cliente solicito dejar el Sitio en Construccion y borrar ya la antigua WEB
